# How to add initial value to TextEditingController with flutter_hooks and riverpod

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, riverpod, flutter-hooks

If I want to add initial value to TextEditingController from Riverpod's provider with hooks, how can I do it?

1. can I use `ref.read(someprovider)` inside of `useTextEditingController` like this?

```
final controller = useTextEditingController(text: ref.read(textProvider));
```

2. or I should use `useEffect` like this

```
final controller = useTextEditingController();
useEffect(() {
      controller.text = ref.read(textProvider);
    }, [controller]);
```

3. is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: are you extended you are widget class with HookWidget?

Comment: The first approach is a good one.